# Pixi js mouse events for top most sprite only

Tags: javascript, sprite, pixi.js

I noticed that in pixi.js version 1.3, as seen in this example, stacking sprites, then click and drag only drags the top most sprite.

```
    bunny.mousedown = bunny.touchstart = function(data)
    {
//      data.originalEvent.preventDefault()
        // store a refference to the data
        // The reason for this is because of multitouch
        // we want to track the movement of this particular touch
        this.data = data;
        this.alpha = 0.9;
        this.dragging = true;
        this.sx = this.data.getLocalPosition(bunny).x * bunny.scale.x;
        this.sy = this.data.getLocalPosition(bunny).y * bunny.scale.y;
    };
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dirkk0/cXfpq/

In version 3.0.3, as seen in this example, the same code causes all the sprites under the mouse to be dragged.

http://jsfiddle.net/9tnaa31z/5/

Is there a way to get only the top most sprite or a way to get a list of all the sprites (in the order rendered)?

Comment: why did you change my tags?  pixi is a webgl and canvas thing, not just javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there may have been a bug in the **3.0.3** version of **PIXI**. I just tried it out with the latest **3.0.5** and it works as expected i.e. it drags only the top-most `Sprite`.

Update the **External Resources** in your fiddle with this [latest version of Pixi.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/3.0.5/pixi.min.js) and it should work.

Reference: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/pixi.js.

Comment: i also tried 3.0.5 right after it was released and it worked as expected.